# How to check supporting recognize speech in keybard

Tags: android

When user clicked on textfield android keyboard appeared. On keyboard exists speech button.

How to check that android keyboard support recognize speech button?

Comment: I doubt you could know. The speech is just another input type. And they are a lot of custom keyboards out there...